# Can't "grab" custom Chrome scrollbar with mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, touch

I've created a custom scrollbar style, and I want to be able to "grab" it with Chrome Android (by tap and dragging on it). It works on the desktop, but with mobile emulation but can't get it.

I've created a JS Fiddle with it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dr8g4g6k/2/

Code:

```css
#container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

#content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}


/* Webkit */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(205, 205, 205, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    test content
  </div>
</div>
```

If you enable Chrome emulation with any device set, and try to scroll by grabbing the scroll bar, you cannot.

You can really use any site to replicate it that has custom webkit scrollbars, even this example here:
https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/

Simply enable mobile emulation and you can't grab it.

Does anyone know how to have custom scrollbars which are always present on Chrome, and still able to "grab" them to scroll like the native ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone else coming across this: Chrome team has decided this is not something they will fix because they don't like custom scrollbars, and because they say that Android being unable to 'grab' scrollbars is by design in general.

So the only answer is to stop using custom scrollbars altogether, since attempting to apply a class to do it on whether it's "mobile" or not is a very bad solution.